# Nodejs Function is returning undefined

Tags: node.js, function, undefined

I have 2 files index.js and models.js

my index.js file requires the model.js file

```
const models = require("./modules/models.js");

app.post('/message', (req, res) => {
    const _lead = models.createLead(req.body)
    _lead.then(l => {
        console.log("resulted in lead", JSON.stringify(l))
        // GETTING UNDEFINED HERE
    })
    // const _message = await models.createMessage(req.body.message)
    res.send();
});
```

My models.js file has a functions that contain Promises

```
const createLead = async function (payload) {
    // Find lead
    let result
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        findLeadById(payload.lead.rid).then(async _lead => {
            // If a lead has not been found
            if (!_lead) {
                if(payload.companyRid != payload.lead.rid){
                await db.collection('leads').add(payload.lead).then((l) => {
                    result = payload.lead
                    result['id'] = l.id
                })
            }
            } else {
                result = _lead
            }
        }).then(() => {
            console.log(" result of create lead ",JSON.stringify(result))
            resolve(result)
        }).catch(error => {
            error.log("reject", error)
            reject(error)
        })
    })
}

const findLeadById = async function (lead) {
    new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const ref = db.collection('leads');
        console.log("finding lead", JSON.stringify(lead))
        await ref.where("rid", "==", lead).get().then((s) => {
            
            let obj = null
            if(s){
                s.forEach(doc => {
                    console.log("found the lead in loop", JSON.stringify(doc.data()))
                    obj = doc.data()
                    obj['id'] = doc.id
                })
            }
            resolve(obj)
        }).catch(error => {
            error.log("reject", error)
            reject(error)
        })
    })
}

exports.createLead = createLead;
exports.findLeadById = findLeadById;
```

The model.js returns an object as expected

```
console.log(" result of create lead ",JSON.stringify(result))
```

However, I'm expecting to see that same object in the index.js in the then block but I'm getting undefined.

```
console.log("resulted in lead", JSON.stringify(l))
// GETTING UNDEFINED HERE
```

The following is not waiting for the associated functions to finish

```
const _lead = models.createLead(req.body)
```

I have also tried adding async and await which also didn't work

```
const _lead = await models.createLead(req.body).then(res => {console.log("result", res) // Still undefined
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use resolve for any success response, and reject for error response. Ex:

```
            await db.collection('leads').add(payload.lead).then((l) => {
                let result = payload.lead
                result['id'] = l.id
                resolve(result)
            })
```

Comment: yeah you can and I do this already however it's still resulting in undefined. I don't think the models.createLead(req.body) call is waiting for the createLead function to finish. Therefore it's undefined. I don't know why it's not waiting for the promise to resolve.